# ubuntu 14.10 sudden freeze + shutdown

Tags: freeze, 14.10, thinkpad

Im on ubuntu 14.10 / Thinkpad t410i from 2010

Linux optimator 3.16.0-25-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 4 12:06:54 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

in the recent days i had some random freezes: suddenly no more reaction to mouse/keyboard and hdd LED is glowing constantly! (suspend to disk maybe? but what would trigger it? can it be a broken display cable (which i probably have..)). 
then after 10-20 seconds the machine powers off.
the freezes usually occured whithin first minutes of usage.
when powering it on again it will either boot normaly or the power led will flash very short and no power up! after some waiting/removing battery it will power up again usually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This would work.

http://www.richxiong.com/2012/11/system-freeze-on-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit/

If this is not working it is a bug. Please refer to this article.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1174275